# BitmapImage Stretch mode to Image tag in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, bitmapimage

I am using  in xaml with some fix image source, later on I wanted to use local image and wanted to assign to the xaml. But I am not able to use stretch in new image created .

Is there any way to use the stretch in other way ?
My code in xaml :

```
 <Image Source="/Assets/Images/fix.png" Visibility="Visible" x:Name="ContentImage" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
```

and in C#

```
if (File.Exists(imagePath))
                        {
                            Image newImage = new Image();
                            BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
                            logo.BeginInit();
                            logo.UriSource = new Uri(imagePath);                                
                            logo.EndInit();
                            newImage.Source = logo;
                            newImage.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
                            ContentImage.Source = newImage.Source;
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to create another Image element. It is also not necessary to call Begin/EndInit. Use the BitmapImage constructor that takes an Uri argument instead.

This should be sufficient:

```
if (File.Exists(imagePath))
{
    ContentImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath));
}
```

Comment: I have tried this earlier , but the issue here is , new image from the path is having size which not fit in the screen, whereas the image used in default is working fine, that's why i thought of creating a new image then manipulate the new image by using the stretch =uniformtoFill

Comment: It's unclear what that means. ContentImage has `Stretch="UniformToFill"` set in XAML, so whatever size it actually is, the newly assigned BitmapImage will be stretched accordingly. Creating a new Image is pointless in any case, since finally you only use its `Source` property. Everything else you may or may not have set is simply ignored.

Comment: even I have tried to get the width and height as per new image and tried to change the contentImage size, still some image are small - some are big , but i want image to show in full screen

Comment: in this default case Stretch="UniformToFill" is working , but when i take image from path, and bind to source it is not working

Comment: Then you have done something wrong that you haven't shown here. Have you tried Stretch=Fill just to see how it looks?